# Why did ; after & return an unexpected token error in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I received the error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

due to the following command:

```
evince foo.pdf bar.pdf &; emacs foo.tex &
```

I is it illegal to separate commands with `;` when using `&` to background a job?  Or is there another reason this didn't work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't need the semicolon.  After it's sent to the background it's free to get another command.

```
evince foo.pdf bar.pdf & emacs foo.tex &
```

Comment: This helped me with an if statement after 2h of swearing. If anyone should need this: `if [ $(ps -ef |grep -c '[p]grep') -eq 0 ]; then nohup sleep 5 > /dev/null 2>&1</dev/null & fi`

Answer (score 18):

BTW, the core issue is that (Bourne-derived) shells do not allow empty commands.

";" and "&" are command terminators, meaning fg and bg respectively.
So "; ;"  (or ";" at the beginning of a line) is also invalid.

(Newline(s) imply ";" if there is a not-yet-terminated command,
unless you use "\" to continue the line.)

Languages vary a lot on these policies:

C-derived languages allow empty statements.

Pascal and PERL have separators, not terminators.

Answer (score -4):

No, it's just confused and can't work out quite what you mean.

You need to group the & with the command that you want to put in the background:

```
$ (evince foo.pdf bar.pdf &); emacs foo.tex &
```

That works fine.  Even more explicit would be:

```
$ (evince foo.pdf bar.pdf &); (emacs foo.tex &)
```

Especially if you then wanted to chain more commands after the end as well.

Comment: There's no need to spawn a subshell just to justify the use of an unnecessary semi-colon. Parentheses aren't just syntax; they cause extra work to be done.